# Handlebars helper for Comma list

Tags: ember.js, helper, handlebars.js

I need to take a comma list from a string and turn each element into a `<li>` item.

So something like the  `red, blue, green` can be passed into a handlebars helper and made into:

`<li>red</li>
<li>green</li>
<li>blue</li>`

I have tried

`

```
Em.Handlebars.helper('decomma', function(value, opts){
  var newArray = value.split(',');
  var html = [];

  $.each(newArray, function(prop, value){
      html.push('<li>'+value+'</li>');
  })

 return html;
})
```

`

but that's just returning the html as a string.

Comment: Tell us what have you tried so far (code) and what problems did you get with that attempt.

Comment: Edited question to reflect what's been tried.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [Ember.js guide on writing Handlebars helpers](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/), Handlebars is going to escape your HTML if you don't return a `SafeString`. Use this instead.

```
return new Handlebars.SafeString(html);
```

Also, just my two cents, you might be better off using a computed property. Something like this:

```
Em.ObjectController.extend({
    value: 'red,blue,green',
    listItems: function() {
        return value.split(',');
    }).property(value)
});
```

Then, in your template:

```
<ul>
    {{#each listItems}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```